# Why isn't the value of a variable that is serving as "count " not resetting to zero when the loops reiterates?

Tags: c++, vector, visual-c++

This is the code that I have written and I am giving you sample inputs and outputs to this just to clear my question even more

Sample input

2 (value of t, which are test cases)
3 (number of inputs )

2 4 2

3
0
2
3

I am getting output as

1
1

I should be getting output as

1
0

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int t;
cin >> t;
while (t--)
{
    vector<ll int> x;
    ll int n;
    cin >> n;
    ll int i, ent;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> ent;
        x.push_back(ent);
    }

    vector<ll int>::iterator y,z;
    for(y=(x.begin());y!=(x.end()-1);y++)
        for (z = (x.begin() + 1); z != (x.end()); z++)
        {
            int count=0;
            if (*y + *z == *y * (*z))
                count++;
        }
    cout << count<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

Updated code: But still having the same problem

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>
    #define ll long long
    int main()
    { 
    int t;
    std ::cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
    std :: vector<ll int> x;
    ll int n;
    std :: cin >> n;
    ll int i, ent;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std :: cin >> ent;
        x.push_back(ent);
    }

    std::vector<ll int>::iterator y,z;

    int count = 0;
    for(y=(x.begin());y!=(x.end()-1);y++)
        for (z = (x.begin()+1); z != (x.end()); z++)
        {
            if (*y + *z == *y * (*z))
                count++;
        }
    std ::cout << count<< std ::endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `int count=0;` you *really* don't want that declared *inside* the for-loop.

Comment: `using namespace std;` strikes again.

Comment: Edit the code to fall within blocks of ```. Avoid declaring namespace for ambiguity and move your counter outside the for-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that you're accessing the variable `count` outside its scope. It is declared in the scope of the inner `for()` loop, and you're trying to print it outside of it. Move its declaration above the `for()` loops

Now, to answer your question. In the second iteration of the `while()` loop (vector 0, 2, 3),
in one of the `for()` loops' iterations, `*x` and `*z` will be equal to 2. What you should have done to avoid it is to initialize z as `z = y + 1`

Comment: Yes, I just made the edits to the count part, I just ran the program again and I am still getting the same error. I am new to vectors and I think I am missing something out here. I think what you are suggesting about vectors is the problem. Would you mind if you can suggest to me what to change?

Comment: I think you're missing his suggestion. instead of z = x.begin()+1 you should have z = y + 1. jserc beat me to this you can see my solution below with some recommended debugging code.

Answer (score 0):

Name conflict between `std::count` and your local `count`. Remove `using namespace std;` and you will have more meaningful error message: as unknown identifier `count`, as `count` should be declared outside of the loop:

```
int count=0;
for(y=(x.begin());y!=(x.end()-1);y++)
    for (z = (x.begin() + 1); z != (x.end()); z++)
    {
         if (*y + *z == *y * (*z))
            count++;
     }
std::cout << count << std::endl;
```

Note: `std::cout << function_name` outputs 1 with implicit bool conversion.

Note: logic of the code itself might still have issues

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that I have made the edits and I am still getting the same problem

Comment: This is the correct solution, if you are still seeing problems it's because you did something wrong. Edit the question and **add** your latest code.

Comment: This may be compiler specific but with gcc if you define a local variable with the same name as one that's in scope from using your actions affect only the local variable and you have to use the namespace to access the other one. 
    namespace test{
    int something=100;
    }

    using namespace test;


    int main()
    {
    int t;
    int something = 50;

    something = 5;
    cout << something << endl;
    cout << test::something << endl;

    exit(0);
    }
using gcc this prints 5 100 ie the local variable overrides the using declaration.

Comment: Done. Thank you for your suggestions you can check out the updated code now.

Comment: @DavidOldford: Scoping rule is not compiler specific. but if local variable goes out of scope (as for original OP's code), you use again the global one.

Comment: OK I think I figured it out. At least in my environment count is not defined as a variable with the headers that are included in this example. That's why the example wouldn't compile for me. I'm not entirely sure what count you're referring to I'm only finding count as a template from including algorithm. Anyway you're correct about the behaviour when it goes out of scope but there are platform differences that affect this specific variable. I thought you were implying that the name override itself just wouldn't work missed that it went out of scope.

Comment: @DavidOldford: But you are right about `std::count` being template... So I'm now unsure.

Comment: @Jarod42 if you got it to compile as it was originally written, then count must be defined somewhere as a variable with the environment you're using, or it allows you to cout a template? Or just a specific compiler bug? Anyway I'm not too worried about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as written should produce that output (if it even complies...) g++ won't compile it because you reference count after the loop it was created in. count is scoped to that loop so it doesn't exist outside. Anyway I assume you're using some compiler switches or a compiler that allows that.

You effectively make one list of numbers and loop through it checking the mathematical relation you coded (ie when two numbers added together is the same as them multiplied together.) Your first loop goes from the first value to the second last value (because you check for equality against end() - 1) I'm not sure if that's what you really wanted or not. Your second loop starts at the second value and then goes till the last value. So in your second test case your second number is 2 and 2 will be used for the parameter *y and then it is the first value in the second loop so you're doing the check with 2 and 2 and 2+2 == 4 == 2*2 so the check passes and count is incremented. Try the code below to get some insight into what you're doing (note that I removed the declaration of count from inside the loop and moved it just above the declaration of y and z which was required for me to compile it with my system):

```
{
    cout << "y:" << *y <<" z:" << *z << endl;
    if (*y + *z == *y * (*z)){
        cout << "match " << *y << " " << *z << endl;
        count++;
        }
}
```

Comment: I have initialized count outside the loop now. Coming to the loops, y runs from the first element to the second last element, and z from the second element to the last element. This is because every element of "x" gets tested for the condition. z is y+1 because when y is on the second last element, the last element will be tested and hence y does not have to go to the end.

Comment: makes sense but I wasn't sure as there was no context. Given this I think jseric's answer solves your problem. It's a good habit to use print statements to clarify what's going on on your code especially if you can do it strategically to isolate exactly where your problems are.